# How do I open a window as a modal dialog in MonoMac using C#?

Tags: c#, macos, monomac

I am developing a Cocoa application with MonoMac (C#).

I have a class `MyWindowController` that inherits `MonoMac.AppKit.NSWindowController`, and open a new instance of this window like this:

```
MyWindowController mwc = new MyWindowController();
mwc.Window.MakeKeyAndOrderFront(this);
```

But how do I open it as a modal dialog? It is imperative that nothing else in my application is executed while the dialog is open, so I cannot use a window sheet (which only blocks the current window). And I can't find anything else that seems to do what I want on my controller. On Windows, I would have done this simply by calling:

```
mwc.ShowDialog();
```

So what I want is the MonoMac equivalent of `ShowDialog()`, I believe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I spent almost three hours trying to figure this out before posting the question, but of course I found the solution right after asking.

It looks like I need to use the NSApplication object:

```
NSApplication.SharedApplication.RunModalForWindow(ewc.Window);
```

Comment: Every time someone asks a question and comes back with the answer, the Internet worked. Thank you!

Comment: Actually, did you ever figure out how to return from the modal call properly?

Comment: No, that wasn't needed for my application, so I never tried to figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

I had success with the answer above, but then had trouble dismissing the modal in the case that the 'close' button was pressed. The solution was to add the code

```
[Export ("windowWillClose:")]
    public void WindowWillClose(NSNotification notification)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("windowWillClose:");
        NSApplication.SharedApplication.StopModal ();
    }
```

to the window controller, then set the window controller to be the window's delegate by, in Interface Builder, right-click the window and drag a line from "delegate" to the "file's owner" block.